# NDB Query StringProperty + StructuredProperty

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

I have this model:

```
class Author(ndb.Model):
    identity = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    email = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)

class Okr(ndb.Model):
    author = ndb.StructuredProperty(Author)
    obj = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    metric = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    img = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)  # image program
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

Also this implementation:

```
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user:
            url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
            url_linktext = 'Logout'

            logging.info(user.email())

            okrs_query = Okr.query(Okr.author.email == user.email()) #problem

            objetives = okrs_query.fetch()

            logging.info(objetives)
```

The query represented by okrs_query = Okr.query(Okr.author.email == user.email()) doesn't work. If I try to do the same query but using OKR.StringProperty it doesn't work but if I use OKR.IntegerProperty it's all good. Thoughts?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "same query but using OKR.StringProperty" and "if I use OKR.IntegerProperty". Also it may help detailing what exactly "doesn't work" (or "#problem") means - the actual error(s)/tracebacks, etc.

Comment: Sorry +Dan you are right, let add more info. If I use into the query "Okr.img" [changing indexed to True] doesn't work but "OKR.metric" works perfectly. I think the problem is when I try to use #strings.

Comment: After changing the index to True did you write new entities? As the already existing ones are not automatically included in the index, you'd have to re-write them (indexing happens only when the entity.put() is called **while** the property's index is True)

Comment: +Dan that was the error, thanks!

Comment: Yes I thought the problem was the query. But the error was on the index. sorry!